# passing a method as parameter in ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, methods, geojson

I'm quite new (3months experience) in programming and this is my first question on stackoverflow!

My task is being able to filter the germany.json based on postcodes that are on https://feed.adcombi.com/feeds/honda_honda_e_sjors?where=reference_code=100120 which looks like this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "created_at": "2021-03-24T11:59:39.996+01:00",
      "filename": "100120.json",
      "id": "honda_honda_e_sjors:11",
      "postal_codes": "48429, 48431, 48432, 48477, 49401, 49413, 49439, 49451, 49477, 49479, 49509, 49596, 49599",
      "reference_code": "100120"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this particular case the reference code i would write in the terminal would be 100120. Then it should give an array of postcodes which also seems to be working.
But then i want my program to look through the whole germany.json and copy the lines of data for every corresponding postcode.
This is what i want the output to look like with reference code 100120:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "color": "blue","postcode": "48429", "locality": "Rheine" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 7.4297101, 52.2978716 ], [ 7.4298946, 52.2987188 ], [ 7.4382758, 52.3006386 ], [ 7.4385288, 52.301023 ], [ 7.4394113, 52.3012676 ], [ 7.4403069, 52.3010089 ], [ 7.4425289, 52.3016208 ], [ 7.4457094, 52.3014547 ], [ 7.4457555, 52.3015988 ], [ 7.4467063, 52.3015154 ], [ 7.4471565, 52.3025382 ], [ 7.4491044, 52.3024085 ], [ 7.4523977, 52.3025542 ], [ 7.4547698, 52.3028872 ], [ 7.4560411, 52.3025233 ], [ 7.4557972, 52.3037031 ], [ 7.4572268, 52.3047581 ], [ 7.457779, 52.3059406 ], [ 7.4652815, 52.3097287 ], [ 7.4645814, 52.3105847 ], [ 7.4662266, 52.3108843 ], [ 7.4689218, 52.3109699 ], [ 7.4744523, 52.308359 ], [ 7.4719334, 52.3069111 ], [ 7.4733928, 52.3058164 ], [ 7.475178, 52.3048224 ], [ 7.4735941, 52.3037406 ], [ 7.4722683, 52.3038996 ], [ 7.4720017, 52.303568 ], [ 7.473869, 52.3018289 ], [ 7.4750335, 52.3016551 ], [ 7.4750169, 52.3011882 ], [ 7.4754261, 52.3007424 ], [ 7.4752526, 52.3006496 ], [ 7.4754315, 52.3004789 ], [ 7.4757296, 52.30058 ], [ 7.4760358, 52.3003645 ], [ 7.4742533, 52.2975185 ], [ 7.4726536, 52.2971197 ], [ 7.4719596, 52.297753 ], [ 7.4700294, 52.2970312 ], [ 7.4718698, 52.295467 ], [ 7.4748202, 52.2928878 ], [ 7.4756151, 52.2910765 ], [ 7.4781203, 52.2914324 ], [ 7.4783797, 52.2903028 ], [ 7.4775529, 52.2902266 ], [ 7.4774514, 52.2907531 ], [ 7.476556, 52.2906509 ], [ 7.4765827, 52.2905372 ], [ 7.4764195, 52.2903453 ], [ 7.4759689, 52.2903008 ], [ 7.4760615, 52.2900044 ], [ 7.4765373, 52.2900458 ], [ 7.4767541, 52.2898019 ], [ 7.4778522, 52.2899934 ], [ 7.4778065, 52.290175 ], [ 7.479387, 52.2903222 ], [ 7.4801969, 52.2894963 ], [ 7.4832889, 52.2881852 ], [ 7.4841692, 52.2860419 ], [ 7.4855174, 52.2859367 ], [ 7.4856236, 52.2841659 ], [ 7.4865284, 52.2831624 ], [ 7.48607, 52.2809204 ], [ 7.4868084, 52.2768236 ], [ 7.4841387, 52.2767119 ], [ 7.4836945, 52.2755122 ], [ 7.4813795, 52.2747901 ], [ 7.4801507, 52.2742778 ], [ 7.4790693, 52.2740089 ], [ 7.4780964, 52.2738805 ], [ 7.4769038, 52.2739906 ], [ 7.4744737, 52.2746485 ], [ 7.4754014, 52.2723641 ], [ 7.4761666, 52.2696219 ], [ 7.4723086, 52.2688678 ], [ 7.4730476, 52.2659341 ], [ 7.4656601, 52.2639338 ], [ 7.464783, 52.2645592 ], [ 7.4623765, 52.2639266 ], [ 7.4613583, 52.2641546 ], [ 7.4615125, 52.2646737 ], [ 7.4607434, 52.2646976 ], [ 7.4583934, 52.2623396 ], [ 7.458527, 52.2613914 ], [ 7.4562637, 52.2592235 ], [ 7.4564317, 52.2599995 ], [ 7.4576418, 52.2609604 ], [ 7.4581912, 52.2614949 ], [ 7.4580951, 52.2623479 ], [ 7.4574865, 52.2629444 ], [ 7.4566463, 52.2635962 ], [ 7.4561313, 52.2644366 ], [ 7.455788, 52.2656973 ], [ 7.4552232, 52.266958 ], [ 7.4550608, 52.2682186 ], [ 7.4549335, 52.2696893 ], [ 7.4548154, 52.2705149 ], [ 7.4544857, 52.2712653 ], [ 7.4537457, 52.2721702 ], [ 7.4531021, 52.2725251 ], [ 7.4524709, 52.2727861 ], [ 7.4515269, 52.2729628 ], [ 7.4499802, 52.2730841 ], [ 7.4477199, 52.2742061 ], [ 7.4461749, 52.2751515 ], [ 7.4448016, 52.2764118 ], [ 7.4436, 52.2773571 ], [ 7.4425114, 52.2783572 ], [ 7.4397254, 52.2804374 ], [ 7.4388812, 52.2812108 ], [ 7.4380273, 52.2821037 ], [ 7.4367339, 52.283038 ], [ 7.4356348, 52.2839802 ], [ 7.4348276, 52.2849204 ], [ 7.4344066, 52.2856814 ], [ 7.4331014, 52.2948063 ], [ 7.4318884, 52.2963084 ], [ 7.4310177, 52.2971339 ], [ 7.4297101, 52.2978716 ] ], [ [ 7.4593695, 52.2956831 ], [ 7.4603951, 52.2935562 ], [ 7.4661655, 52.2943063 ], [ 7.4653905, 52.2966579 ], [ 7.4648712, 52.2980297 ], [ 7.4644264, 52.2983292 ], [ 7.4648145, 52.2984366 ], [ 7.4650654, 52.2993927 ], [ 7.4644069, 52.2991796 ], [ 7.4636626, 52.2975869 ], [ 7.4593695, 52.2956831 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "color": "blue","postcode": "48431", "locality": "Rheine" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 7.3963299, 52.2852607 ], [ 7.4019373, 52.2866851 ], [ 7.4040757, 52.2873537 ], [ 7.408115, 52.2891269 ], [ 7.4091604, 52.2916266 ], [ 7.4094456, 52.2932833 ], [ 7.411196, 52.2940031 ], [ 7.4158301, 52.2954537 ], [ 7.4176239, 52.2962705 ], [ 7.4208628, 52.297014 ], [ 7.4217796, 52.295405 ], [ 7.4233354, 52.2946346 ], [ 7.4252911, 52.2946575 ], [ 7.4261133, 52.2944289 ], [ 7.4277686, 52.2939053 ], [ 7.4310177, 52.2971339 ], [ 7.4318884, 52.2963084 ], [ 7.4331014, 52.2948063 ], [ 7.4344066, 52.2856814 ], [ 7.4348276, 52.2849204 ], [ 7.4356348, 52.2839802 ], [ 7.4367339, 52.283038 ], [ 7.4380273, 52.2821037 ], [ 7.4388812, 52.2812108 ], [ 7.4397254, 52.2804374 ], [ 7.4425114, 52.2783572 ], [ 7.4436, 52.2773571 ], [ 7.4448016, 52.2764118 ], [ 7.4461749, 52.2751515 ], [ 7.4477199, 52.2742061 ], [ 7.4499802, 52.2730841 ], [ 7.4515269, 52.2729628 ], [ 7.4524709, 52.2727861 ], [ 7.4531021, 52.2725251 ], [ 7.4537457, 52.2721702 ], [ 7.4544857, 52.2712653 ], [ 7.4548154, 52.2705149 ], [ 7.4549335, 52.2696893 ], [ 7.4550608, 52.2682186 ], [ 7.4552232, 52.266958 ], [ 7.455788, 52.2656973 ], [ 7.4561313, 52.2644366 ], [ 7.4566463, 52.2635962 ], [ 7.4574865, 52.2629444 ], [ 7.4580951, 52.2623479 ], [ 7.4581912, 52.2614949 ], [ 7.4576418, 52.2609604 ], [ 7.4564317, 52.2599995 ], [ 7.4562637, 52.2592235 ], [ 7.4539155, 52.2580164 ], [ 7.4528919, 52.2568467 ], [ 7.4411018, 52.2546264 ], [ 7.4319585, 52.257779 ], [ 7.4285488, 52.2585521 ], [ 7.4242947, 52.2597772 ], [ 7.41944, 52.259387 ], [ 7.419104, 52.2589653 ], [ 7.4183567, 52.258896 ], [ 7.4182001, 52.2591651 ], [ 7.4126074, 52.2585032 ], [ 7.4112517, 52.262118 ], [ 7.4107765, 52.2651355 ], [ 7.4104795, 52.2661534 ], [ 7.4102202, 52.2692209 ], [ 7.4116788, 52.2705638 ], [ 7.4104964, 52.2711973 ], [ 7.4108855, 52.2718284 ], [ 7.4136881, 52.274587 ], [ 7.4130105, 52.2747979 ], [ 7.4128588, 52.2747091 ], [ 7.4128114, 52.2744531 ], [ 7.4126077, 52.2740778 ], [ 7.4119147, 52.273779 ], [ 7.4105048, 52.2725911 ], [ 7.4109263, 52.2723397 ], [ 7.4106688, 52.2721118 ], [ 7.410284, 52.2720854 ], [ 7.4100681, 52.2719167 ], [ 7.4102575, 52.2712785 ], [ 7.4095267, 52.2705163 ], [ 7.4086649, 52.2707342 ], [ 7.4088568, 52.2711498 ], [ 7.4082632, 52.2714474 ], [ 7.4081134, 52.271932 ], [ 7.4085428, 52.2720282 ], [ 7.4074575, 52.2729249 ], [ 7.4070921, 52.2730525 ], [ 7.406918, 52.2736317 ], [ 7.4067228, 52.2744788 ], [ 7.4063787, 52.2744325 ], [ 7.4062955, 52.2745838 ], [ 7.407044, 52.2749572 ], [ 7.4067781, 52.2755598 ], [ 7.4063416, 52.2754922 ], [ 7.4062063, 52.2757497 ], [ 7.406614, 52.27584 ], [ 7.4063198, 52.2764512 ], [ 7.406843, 52.2768402 ], [ 7.406697, 52.2771379 ], [ 7.4030765, 52.2788434 ], [ 7.4032262, 52.2799204 ], [ 7.4011348, 52.2799673 ], [ 7.4011994, 52.2802026 ], [ 7.4007258, 52.2803447 ], [ 7.4007474, 52.2809628 ], [ 7.4006533, 52.2814193 ], [ 7.3990436, 52.2812305 ], [ 7.3986753, 52.2812263 ], [ 7.3980513, 52.2810657 ], [ 7.3969684, 52.2806814 ], [ 7.3967381, 52.2809409 ], [ 7.397828, 52.2813077 ], [ 7.3976831, 52.2814913 ], [ 7.3985298, 52.2817656 ], [ 7.3982415, 52.2820581 ], [ 7.3980639, 52.2819998 ], [ 7.3979162, 52.2820174 ], [ 7.3976664, 52.2822349 ], [ 7.3981206, 52.2824191 ], [ 7.3988776, 52.2816042 ], [ 7.3992345, 52.2816373 ], [ 7.399422, 52.2819418 ], [ 7.3997443, 52.2820569 ], [ 7.398332, 52.2833617 ], [ 7.398877, 52.2842112 ], [ 7.3973282, 52.2845048 ], [ 7.3963299, 52.2852607 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "color": "blue","postcode": "48432", "locality": "Rheine" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 7.4593695, 52.2956831 ], [ 7.4636626, 52.2975869 ], [ 7.4644069, 52.2991796 ], [ 7.4650654, 52.2993927 ], [ 7.4648145, 52.2984366 ], [ 7.4644264, 52.2983292 ], [ 7.4648712, 52.2980297 ], [ 7.4653905, 52.2966579 ], [ 7.4661655, 52.2943063 ], [ 7.4603951, 52.2935562 ], [ 7.4593695, 52.2956831 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

And so on but with each of postcodes.

Right now i am getting back an empty array, but what i want is a new geojson with only the corresponding postcodes, What do i adjust to make my code have the output that looks like the geojson as seen above?

My code:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pry'

def parse_data_from(file:)
  raw_content = File.read(file)
  JSON.parse(raw_content)
end

def get_postal_codes(reference_codes)
  reference_codes.each do |reference_code|
    raw_content = open("https://feed.adcombi.com/feeds/honda_honda_e_sjors?where=reference_code=#{reference_code}").read
    data_hash = JSON.parse(raw_content)
    codes = []
    data_hash['result'].each do |a|
      codes << a['postal_codes']
    end
  end
end

def make_geojsons(get_postal_codes)
  data = parse_data_from(file: 'germany.json')
  features = data['features']

  result = []
  get_postal_codes.each do |postal_code|
    features.each do |feature|
      next unless feature['properties']['postcode'] == postal_code

      result << feature
    end
  end

  File.open('temp.json', 'w') do |f|
    f.puts(JSON.generate(result))
  end
end

puts "provide reference code here"
reference_codes = gets.chomp.split(' ')
get_postal_codes(reference_codes)
make_geojsons(get_postal_codes)
```

Hope my explanation is clear, if not let me know!

Apoligies if the code is messy, i'm still pretty new and open for all sorts of feedback and explanations! Thanks in advance.

PS: can i just add jsons like this on stackoverflow as well? The jsons are quite big and i'm afraid it will bring some complications if i just copy paste it here as code.

Comment: I don't see the question, but you meant passing the result of invoking `get_postal_codes` with `reference_codes` as the argument to the `make_geojsons` method? If so you can just do `make_geojsons(get_postal_codes(reference_codes))` and/or store the result of `get_postal_codes(reference_codes)` in a variable.

Comment: @Jaapiekrekel : It's a good idea to show the world the code which you have written, but what exactly is your question? Do you need a code review?

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry you're totally right. What i want is to make new geojsons with only the geojson data if it matches a postcode from the array. 
The geojson is so big (over 9000 lines of data) so i essentially want to filter out like 10 lines and create a new json with those new lines.

Comment: @SebastianPalma When i do this i get back an array but it's just creating an empty array in the temp.json
What needs to happen is that the data from the germany.json gets copied and pasted to a new file for each postcode in the array if you get what i mean. Sorry im bad at explaining it.

Comment: And this explanation should go into the question, not in the comment. So, the behaviour of `make_geojsons` is different than you expected? In this case, describe in your question what effect you would expect, and what you actually see - then we have something to discuss.

Comment: @user1934428 i've rewritten the whole question to hopefully be a lot more clear.
Let me know if you can work with this.

Comment: shouldn't you return the value stored in `result` from `make_geojsons`? You currently return the result of the `each` method.